# Bootstrap - Collapse item with 'special' attribute on it

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

this is my first question so don't eat me.

I want to use collapse from bootstrap but I don't want to use id/class in data-target/aria-controls. Is there a way to call it by attribute like that ?

```
 <a href="" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-target="data-s-collapse='item'" aria-controls="data-s-collapse='item'">
 </a>
 <div class="collapse" data-s-collapse="item">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can! The `data-target` attributes accepts any valid CSS Selector ([Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-data-attributes-3)).

So using data-attribute CSS selectors ([CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/)) you can do exactly what you want.

Here's a minimal working example (only tested in Chrome. Formatted for readability).

```
<a href="#" 
   role="button"
   data-toggle="collapse" 
   aria-expanded="false" 
   data-target="[data-s-collapse='item']" 
   aria-controls="[data-s-collapse='item']">I'm a button
 </a>
 <div class="collapse" data-s-collapse="item">
   I'm some stuff in a collapsible
 </div>
```

[Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/TEojSr7ok5)

Should work in all browsers that support attribute selectors, which were present in CSS level 2.1, so should be fine across all in use browsers - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2